# Spring Integration: location of logging and message history files

Tags: spring-integration

Spring Integration defines both `<int:logging-channel-adapter/>` and `<int:message-history/>` elements for logging. What is the default directory/folder where these files are placed? Also, is this location configurable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. `<int:message-history/>` isn't for logging. It just stores the 'journey' of the message to its headers. Right, it is done in some convenient form, which is useful to be logged.
2. `<int:logging-channel-adapter/>` it doesn't store anything to the disk. This component just does `log.debug()`, `log.info()` etc.. Where logs are stored it's up to logging system configuration.
3. How does your logging system works is out of Spring Integration scope: you can simply store logs to file, or to the DB, or send them to JMS, or AMQP, or just show in console. So, investigate, please, how you can fix your 'issue' with you logging system: log4j, commons-logging, slf4j etc.